# Reducing the use of global $post

Tags: custom-post-types, globals

When creating meta boxes, in each meta box function it seems a reference to the `global $post` is passed as a parameter `($event)`. I prefer this as it seems consistent and less likely to fudge the `$post` var by declaring it explicitly as I have read elsewhere.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'events_admin');
function events_admin() 
{
     add_meta_box('display_events_date_meta_box',
        'Dates',
        'display_events_date_meta_box',
        'events', 'normal', 'high'
    );

}

function display_events_date_meta_box($event) // Referenced
{
     //$event in this case is the $post global
}
```

I have created a filter and various other functions which currently just use the `global $post` variable.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'test' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'test' );
function test()
{
    global $post; // Declared explicitly
}
```

Is there a standard / recommended way to pass the `global $post` variable as a parameter to these functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I need to deal with `$post` variable on admin, I usually use a class to early catch and wrap global `$post` variable, obtaining an *universal* way to access to it, without repetitely relying on the global variable.

```
class MyAdminPost 
{

   private static $post;

   public static function init()
   {
     $p_get = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'post', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
     $p_post = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'post', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
     if ($p_get > 0 || $p_post > 0) {
       self::$post = $p_get > 0 ? get_post($p_get) : get_post($p_post);
     } elseif ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'post-new.php') {
       add_action('new_to_auto-draft', function(\WP_Post $post) {
         if (is_null(MyAdminPost::$post)) {
           MyAdminPost::$post = $post;
         }
       }, 0);
     }
   }

   public function get()
   {
     return self::$post;
   }
}

add_action('admin_init', array('MyAdminPost', 'init'));
```

On early stage of admin loading, that is `'admin_init'` hook, `'MyAdminPost'` class looks for post ID variable sent with request and store related post object.

That works on `post.php` page, but not on `post-new.php`, because on that page post ID is not sent with request because it does't exist yet. In that case I add a callback to `'new_to_auto-draft'` that is one the [`"{old_status}_to_{new_status}"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/) hooks to store the post immediately after it is created on `post-new.php` page.

In this way, in both pages, post object is stored in a class property very early.

## Usage Example (Procedural)

```
function get_my_admin_post()
{
   static $post = null;
   if (is_null($post) && did_action('admin_init')) {
     $map = new MyAdminPost();
     $post = $map->get(); 
   }

   return $post;
}

add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'test');

function test()
{
    $post = get_my_admin_post();
}
```

## Usage Example (OOP)

```
class ClassThatUsesPostObject
{

  private $post_provider;

  function __construct(MyAdminPost $map)
  {
     $this->post_provider = $map;
  }

  function doSomethingWithPost()
  {
    $post = $this->post_provider->get();
  }
}
```

## Benefits

- you can obtain post object very early in a way that is compatible to both `post.php` and `post-new.php` pages, so in **all** the hooks fired in those pages you have access to post object with no effort
- you remove any global `$post` variable reference in your code
- your code becomes testable in isolation

Comment: The Procedural and OOP code were very helpful, thankyou. +1

Comment: This is a dangerous road to follow in general. It means that you cache $post without any way to invalidate the cache therefor you might end up with stale $post when some other code changes it. If you control all the code in the site there is no problem with that but if you have some third party code that might change the $post for whatever reason, that code might break if it has any interaction with your code because it assume that your code operates on the $post object it set while it doesn't.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Not agree. This class responsibility is: "Give the post object of the related **admin** post page I am in". In admin post page, there's only **one** post that's *under editing*: you can manipulate a lot of posts, but while in admin post page if you want to know which post you're editing this class is perfect. Moreover, if some code change global post in admin post page w/out redirecting page or w/out restoring it after a temporary switching (for any reason) that code is a bug. Even during temporary swithing, class is useful if you want to know the post whose editing page you're in.

Comment: @MarkKaplun As a comparison, think in frontend to a page template that is used to display a secondary loop. During that loop, global post refers to every post in the loop. Fine. But if before, during or after that secondary loop you need the *page* object of the page you are in? There is `get_queried_object()` that's handy. It is available in admin too, but doesn't work for new post page and is available only after the query. This class fills the gap.

Comment: @G.M., I am not disagreeing with your code, just wanted to state that it has risks if anybody going to do the same everywhere. Even for the post edit page I can think of a post revision tracking plugin (git style) which will use post=X&revision=Y parameters and fetches the $post based on both parameters and not only on the post one.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Note that WP [sets global post like my code does](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/post.php#L19). It means that if a custom code like in your example replaces global post variable, you can bet that potentially hundreds of plugins will break, and also a large number of core functions will break because WP itself assumes that global post is the one whose ID is set in `$_GET` or `$_POST` `'post'` variable. That's the reason I said permanently replacing global post with a custom post object is a bug.

Comment: @MarkKaplun If I catch you or anyone else modifying globals on the fly, I'll personally shoot the one responsible exactly where he stands.

Comment: @G.M. Too bad that `INPUT_REQUEST` isn't implemented yet. Anyway, I wonder how reliable your preference of `$_GET` is, based on `$p_get > 0`.

Comment: @kaiser `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` makes `filter_input()` return a string that contains only integer chars. So if there is a valid post id in `$_GET['post']` than `$p_get > 0` is always true (note that `0` is not a valid id).

Comment: I meant why to prefer `$_GET` over `$_POST` that way.

Comment: Because is how `$_REQUEST` works. Try to send 2 values for same variable, but one on `$_GET` and one on `$_POST`. If you get the value with `$_REQUEST` the value on `$_GET` *wins*. @kaiser

Comment: @G.M. Awesome. Didn't know that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @kaiser, :) but what do you think http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata does? I don't think I ever saw it used on the admin side but it is an official API and I will not be surprised to find out that someone uses it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun This would be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

`admin_head-{$hook_suffix}` is triggered on every admin page, so passing anything to that function probably wouldn't make sense. You can see in source that no arguments are passed:

```
do_action( "admin_head-$hook_suffix" );
```

In many cases you have no alternative to `global $post`, and if you look through just about any core source file, you'll see `global` litter everywhere, due to the mostly procedural construction of core and a primary objective to maintain backward compatibility. It's messy but mostly harmless **if you're just accessing its value within a known context**.

Answer (score 1):

You can not easily modify the parameters used with an existing filter/action as they are set by the "calling" code, therefor you can't inject additional parameters. There might be some possibility to do that by hacking the core code behind do_action/apply_filter but if you will succeed you most likely will break all the other code that hooks on those actions/filters.